# Select all nodes of a type under a given node

Tags: java, xpath

i'm new to XNode and want to select all nodes of a type under a given node. In the following example, i'm looking for all bar nodes beneath the foo node.

```
 <node>
    <foo>
     <bar/>
     <div><bar/></div>
     <ul>
      <li><bar/>
     </ul>
     <p>foobar</p>
    </foo>
    <bar/>
</node>
```

My Application gets the foo node (org.w3c.dom.Node):

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//bar", fooNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Returns all bar nodes of the whole document, not from the fooNode even though i passed the node and not the whole document.

Comment: How is fooNode initialized?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what you mean with initialized? The Node is the <foo> node, selected with XPath

Comment: xpath.evaluate("//bar", fooNode, ...)  in this line what is fooNode equal to? And initialized just means setting variable to some value for the first time

Answer (score 1):

> Returns all bar nodes of the whole document, not from the fooNode even
>   though i passed the node and not the whole document.

That's the expected behavior for an [absolute location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath) as `//bar`. Use a relative location path as `.//bar` or `descendant-or-self::bar` or `descendant::bar`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but

```
//foo/descendant-or-self::bar
```

selects the 3 `</bar>`s inside `<foo>`.